# Azure batch Application package not getting copied to Working Directory of Task

Tags: azure-batch

I have created Azure Batch pool with Linux Machine and specified Application Package for the Pool.

My command line is

```
command='python $AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_scriptv1_1/tasks/XXX/get_XXXXX_data.py',
python3: can't open file '$AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_scriptv1_1/tasks/XXX/get_XXXXX_data.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

when i connect to node and look at working directory non of the Application Package files are present there.

How do i make sure that files from Application Package are available in working directory or I can invoke/execute files under Application Package from command line ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your async operation have proper `await` in place before you start using the package in your code.

Also please share your design \ pseudo-code scenario and how you are approaching it as a design?

Further to add:

Seems like this one is pool level package.

- The error seems like that the application env variable is either incorrectly used or there is some other user level issue. Please checkout linmk below and specially the section where use of env variable is mentioned.

This seems like user level issue because In case of downloading the package resource, if there will be an error it will be visible to you via exception handler or at the tool level is you are using batch explorer \ Batch-labs or code level exception handling.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages

***Reason \ Rationale:***

- If the pool level or the task application has error, an error-list will come back if there was an error in the application package then it will be returned as the `UserError or and AppPackageError` which will be visible in the exception handle of the code.
- **Key** you can always RDP into your node and checkout the package availability: information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics#connecting-to-compute-nodes

I once created a small sample to help peeps around so this resource might help you to checkeout the use [here](https://github.com/Tatsinnit/quick_sample_batchapppkgworking).

Hope rest helps.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the application package with version string is formatted as:

`AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_{0}_{1}`

On Windows it is formatted as:

`AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_APPLICATIONID#version`

Where 0 is the application name and 1 is the version.

`$AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_scriptv1_1` will take you to the root folder where the application was unzipped.

Does this "exact" path exist in that location?

`tasks/XXX/get_XXXXX_data.py`

You can see more information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages

**Edit:** Just saw this question: "or can I invoke/execute files under Application Package from command line"

Yes you can invoke and execute files from the application package directory with the environment variable above.

If you type `env` on the node you will see the environment variables that have been set.